# Does it matter if your passenger root is in a seperate location than the rest of your gem env?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, rubygems, passenger

I get a 502 bad gateway if I try to point both the Passenger_root with the rest of my gems.

**my nginx.conf** *(I don't use both passenger roots)*

```
env               GEM_HOME=/home/shadyfront/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@revolt;

http {
 # this line will pass, but I am worried that it's not detecting a particular gem is checked out because it's looking for the passenger_root in a different location.
 # this is also the default gem install before I installed RVM 
 passenger_root /home/shadyfront/webapps/revolting_age/gems/gems/passenger-2.2.15;

 # this line fails even though this is where the other passenger can be found
 passenger_root  /home/shadyfront/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p330@revolt/gems/passenger-2.2.15;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. But look in your web server error log to find out what the *real* error message is.